# php sessions get mixed

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a page called mypage.php when i store users profiles with a $_GET variable(id) like mypage.php?id=1 or ?id=2 etc...

when i log in and i am id=1, when i go to id=2 i get this user's ID as my session, and i dont have any variable to set my session this user's when i go to this profile..

i only set to the user the session user_id as the user id when logged in... like

```
$_SESSION["user_id"] = 1;//fetched via the user login details
```

it automatically does that...

Also when i do an ajax request my sessions get lost with no reason...

this happens on LIVE server but not on localhost.

**EDIT:** i noticed that my sessions get mixed up within the server folders, i have 2 apps using the same session to store the logged in user ID(user_id is the session name), so when i log in on first app and go to 2nd i appear as logged in even if i am not registered)... so why this happens?

Comment: Are you definitely running session_start() on your AJAX page?

Comment: i am including my config.php file on top of all pages. this is my config.php, <?php
ob_start();
ob_clean();
session_start();
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
mysql_select_db('mydb') or die(mysql_error());
?>

Comment: what i noticed is that my sessions get mixed up since i have multiple scripts in my site and i use in some projects the same session variable(user_id)... any way i can make the sessions work within the folder and not the whole site?

Comment: @fxuser: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php   lets you control the session cookie's parameters - set a path on the cookie and you can have per-directory sessions.

Comment: @Marc B: i tried using session_set_cookie_params(0, '/path/to/folder/', '.website.com');  before session_start() but still take problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `session_start()`, call [session_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) in order to set a unique name for each application's session.

Comment: i tried it but still the problem persists.In the same folder, when i go to other user profiles, it changes my user_id session to this user without me having a function to do it and also it Nulls some other sessions i have for my user.